# Select file from command-line

Tags: macos, command-line

Is it possible to launch Finder from the command-line to perform a file select action?

The purpose of this would be for the end user to, when running a shell script, be able to select a file using a GUI instead of typing in the path and filename.

Comment: How about `open path/to/dir -a Finder` and then let the user drag and drop the file ? or use `ls` if you dont want GUI.. ?

Comment: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640419/open-file-dialog-box

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/UsingtheOpenandSavePanels/UsingtheOpenandSavePanels.html

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopenpanel?language=objc

Comment: the `open path/to/dir -a Finder` is a good idea. I'm writing a few scripts for a non-technical user and having a GUI file selection would be extremely helpful if it's even possible.

Comment: The problem with that panel approach is to create a boilerplate app that does nothing but opens a less functional finder window. And it may not even run if it's not codesigned. Best is to tell the user in CLI how to copy file paths (option + command + c) or filenames (command + c) and proper use of quotes. \\ If not, look into AppleScript to achieve this. But that still needs user permissions.

Comment: See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250067410 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346171/writing-gui-frontend-for-commandline-application-in-mac-os-x

Comment: See [Pashua](https://www.bluem.net/en/projects/pashua/) and [CocoaDialog](https://cocoadialog.com/v2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to launch Finder from the command-line to perform a file select action?

There's some confusion about Finder and what it is/does.  You don't "launch" finder in the conventional sense.  It's always running. It's the *graphical* interface through which you interact with your Mac system.  You open a file using Finder's file selection tools or view the contents using Preview, etc.

[Get to know the Finder on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201732)

> The purpose of this would be for the end user to, when running a shell script, be able to select a file using a GUI instead of typing in the path and filename.

Bouncing back and forth between a GUI and a text environment is inefficient.  Why would you begin typing a command in a text environment, then switch to a GUI to get your file, then switch back to text?  Instead, you create the *File Selection Dialog Box* right there in the text environment.

There's a tool called `dialog` available on [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/dialog/summary) and on [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/dialog#default) that allows you to create dialog and file selection boxes in your text environment.  Below is an example of the file selection box from the [`deletefile.sh` script](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_file_selection_box) (similar to what you described).

[image: FSelect Dialog Box]

For more examples of the different dialog boxes you can create, see:  https://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog-figures.html

Comment: While switching between text and gui applications is inefficient, it makes sense for a script that is being written for a non-technical user who has little to no experience with command-line interfaces. I appreciate the added context and the list of widgets! I'll check those out!

Comment: I think there’s some in “Oh My ZSH” ( or available as plugins). I don’t use that tool personally, but you may run across it in your travels.

Answer (score 4):

You can launch GUI Dialog to select a file in shell script with following code:

```
theSelectedFile="$(osascript -l JavaScript -e 'a=Application.currentApplication();a.includeStandardAdditions=true;a.chooseFile({withPrompt:"Please select a file to process:"}).toString()')"

echo "Selected file: $theSelectedFile"
```

You can customize Window title: see `withPrompt`attribute

Answer (score 0):

[tselect](https://github.com/yujinqiu/tselect)

My tiny swift cli tselect (terminal selection file) may meet your need.